# Numerate the org headings

Tags: elisp

I want to numerate the org-headings from:

```
* heading how
* heading are
* heading you
```

to

```
* 1.heading how
* 2.heading are
* 3.heading you
```

So I compose a `numerate-org-heading` as:

```
(defun numerate-org-heading (args)
  "Numerate org headings"
  (interactive "s")
  (let ((count 0))
    (while (re-search-forward args nil t)
      (setq count (1+ count))
      (replace-match (concat "\1" (string count)
                             (forward-char 1))))))
```

Unfortunately, It report error of `Wrong type argument: stringp, ^*` when i call `numerate-org-heading` interactively and feed it with string "^*".

Could you please give any hints to solve the problem?

---

Modified the function and it works now for particular cases:

```
(defun numerate-org-heading (args)
  "Numerate org headings"
  (interactive "s")
  (let ((count 0))
    (while (re-search-forward args nil t)
      (setq count (1+ count))
      (replace-match (concat "* " (number-to-string count) ".")
                     (forward-char 1))))))
```

Comment: I cannot replicate the same error.. partly because the example function provided will not run as you appear to be missing close brackets

Comment: thank you sir @KindStranger, I modified the function and it works for particular cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `args` as a matching group and capture any trailing space, you can replace that back as group 1 (`"\\1"`) followed by your numeration e.g. `1.`

```
(defun numerate-org-heading (args)
  "Numerate org headings"
  (interactive "s")
  (let ((count 0))
    (while (re-search-forward (concat "\\(" args "[ \\t]*\\)") nil t)
      (setq count (1+ count))
      (replace-match (concat "\\1" (number-to-string count) ".")))))
```